# Custom claims do not persist outside of middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create custom claims and persist them through the session. Unfortunately, it looks like they don't persist outside of the middleware itself. Am I missing something?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed;
using SRD.Data;
using SRD.Extensions;

namespace SRD.Security
{
    public class ServerClaimsMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ServerClaimsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        private const string ClaimsLastCheckedKey = "ClaimsLastChecked";

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, DbContext dbContext, IDistributedCache cache)
        {
            if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var claimsLastChecked = await cache.RetrieveFromCache<DateTimeOffset?>(ClaimsLastCheckedKey);
                if (!claimsLastChecked.HasValue)
                {
                    var cs = new List<Claim>();

                    using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
                    {
                        if (context.User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
                        {
                            var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, identity.Name);
                            if (user != null) cs.Add(new Claim(CustomClaimType.DisplayName.ToString(), user.DisplayName));
                        }
                    }

                    var roles = await dbContext.Roles.All();
                    foreach (var role in roles.Where(r => context.User.IsInRole(r.ADGroupName)))
                    {
                        var roleClaims = dbContext.Claims.ByRole(role.ADGroupName);
                        var customClaims = roleClaims.Select(x => new Claim(CustomClaimType.Permission.ToString(), x.Name));
                        cs.AddRange(customClaims);
                    }
                    if (cs.Any()) context.User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(cs, "Kerbros"));

                    await cache.SaveToCache(ClaimsLastCheckedKey, DateTimeOffset.Now, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0));
                }
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }

    public static class ServerClaimsMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseServerClaimsMiddleware(
            this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<ServerClaimsMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding them to the ClaimsPrincipal, but that doesn't persist the data anywhere.
When ASP.NET Core authenticates a request, it creates a ClaimsPrincipal from the cookie/token/something else.
It does not go the other way around automatically; modifying the principal is purely in-memory.

If your app is the one creating the cookie/token,
I think you can write a new one by calling `context.SignInAsync()` in your middleware after modifying the principal.

```
// you need this import
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

// In your middleware Invoke()
await context.SignInAsync(context.User);
```

You can also specify an authentication scheme to SignInAsync() if you have not configured a default sign-in scheme.